# ZendFramework2 + Doctrine ODM Module Enable Metadata Caching

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm using ZF2 and Doctrine's ODM module.

The problem:

On each request my proxies and hydrators are being regenerated. This causes random errors. See https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/484 for more details.

After Doctrine's docs about MetadataCaching http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/metadata-drivers.html

I clearly set ApcCache to be the default metadata cache implementation.

Debugging my document manager i get the following:

```
[mongoCmd] => $
[retryConnect] => 0
[retryQuery] => 0
[autoGenerateProxyClasses] => 0
[proxyDir] => data/DoctrineMongoODMModule/Proxy
[proxyNamespace] => DoctrineMongoODMModule\Proxy
[autoGenerateHydratorClasses] => 0
[hydratorDir] => data/DoctrineMongoODMModule/Hydrator
[hydratorNamespace] => DoctrineMongoODMModule\Hydrator
[defaultDB] => 
[metadataCacheImpl] => Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache Object
```

So both autogenerate proxies and autogenerate hydrators are off, the ApcCache object is clearly set as the metadataCacheImplementation, but instead of reading the metadata from the cached classes, Doctrine regenerates the classes on each following request.

Any ideas on how to force Doctrine to read the metadata from cache rather than creating new classes on each request.

Thanks.

Marko